# How to get todays current steps?

Tags: android

In newer versions of android there is a TYPE_STEP_COUNTER which allows someone to count the steps the person is taking in the application however it doesn't let you ask it for the steps its counted without it sending an event. In my application I'm trying to just see what the total steps for the day is when the app opens. Is there any way of finding this information out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. If you read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

it says

> A sensor of this type returns the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated.

So it will only tell you the total steps taken since the device last turned on.

Unless I have missed something you will need to create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to keep track of steps over a given time period.